# XBee Send To All

Tags: arduino, xbee, zigbee

I have a simple xbee network operating where there are a bunch of slaves operating remotely and all talking to one master, who is connected to the server computer. That works no problem.

The slaves all send their ID as part of the packet and I'd like to have the master deliberately send an Ack after a delay. I'm trying to figure out how to do this efficiently and it seems that the only plausible way that doesn't involve reprogramming the master before each Ack is to send the Ack to all slaves and have them ignore the packet if it's not meant for them.

That solution is ok - I just can't figure out the command to use to do this. Is there some sort of Serial sendAll command? All of the devices are on the same ATID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically in this situation, you would configure the master in API mode so you would get "Receive Explicit" frames with source addressing information, and could send with the "Transmit Explicit" frame type, and include addressing information in your frames.

If you use AT mode (transparent serial mode), then you're stuck having to change the DH and DL parameters on your coordinator every time you want to change who you send to.  You should avoid using broadcast packets, since each one results in lots of network traffic (IIRC, each router will send the broadcast packet three times).

I do not know of a good XBee library on the Arduino, but it might be possible to port Digi's Open Source [ANSI C XBee Host Library](https://github.com/digidotcom/xbee_ansic_library) to that platform.

Comment: Aye, I realized the API route shortly after posting the question. Thanks tomlogic.